# How to pass custom parameter to event handler

Tags: c#, lambda, event-handling

I have the following code, which based on a condition assigns or unassigns a parameterized event handler to some objects, using an anonymous (lambda) method:

```
{
    if (condition)

        foreach (var channel in dataSource.Channels)
        {
            channel.NewSamples += (s, vals) => AddSamples(channel.Index, vals);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var channel in dataSource.Channels)
        {
            channel.NewSamples -= (s, vals) => AddSamples(channel.Index, vals);
        }

    }
}

private void AddSamples(int channelIndex, IEnumerable<int> samples)
{
    /// do work
}
```

I suspect this wouldn't unsubscribe correctly, and so I would like to pass `channel.Index` as parameter to a named handler, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your handlers in a dictionary, by channel, like this:

```
Dictionary<Channel, YourEventHandler> _handlers = new Dictionary<Channel, YourEventHandler>();

...

if (condition)
    foreach (var channel in dataSource.Channels)
    {
        if (!_handlers.ContainsKey(channel)) {
            YourEventHandler handler = (s, vals) => AddSamples(channel.Index, vals);
            channel.NewSamples += handler;
            _handlers[channel] = handler;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    foreach (var channel in dataSource.Channels)
    {
        if (_handlers.ContainsKey(channel)) {
             channel.NewSamples -= _handlers[channel];
             _handlers.Remove(channel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When assignment happens, you have different values for `channel.Index`, but no way to tell each handler which `channelIndex` value you are passing.  That's why I didn't go for this approach. Do you think this can be fixed?

Comment: @heltonbiker yeah what I wrote before was complete nonsense for your case. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Hm, the dictionary is an interesting idea. Gonna test it today and give some feedback asap. Thanks for now!